# Could dragon balls bring the universes back?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super, a giant tournament between the most powerful fighters of eight different universes is currently happening. The seven universes to lose will be erased by the God of all universes.

**If that happens, could dragonballs possibly save the erased universes ?**

Comment: The super dragon balls might be able to save the universe. But considering that it will go against the wishes of Zen-chan, I doubt it will ever happen, unless you imply that the dragon isn't afraid of him, which is very unlikely.

Comment: Spoiler: ʞɔɐq ɯǝɥʇ ƃuıɹq pıp ʎǝɥʇ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal super dragon balls can revive the universes yes. As it was said during their first encounter that this Shenron was powerfull enough to grant "any" wish.

However I doubt that the Super Shenron would go against Zen-oh as he would be at the risk of being erased. This is my personal thought, but based on the fear of the earth Shenron towards Beerus I can asume that Omega Shenron has the same fear towards Zen-oh. Due to this he most likely would refuse to grant the wish.

Comment: Calling it now: Goku loves Battle and loves fighting the guys from other Universes, therefore his wish will be to bring the other Universes into Universe 7. That way he gets strong people to fight whenever he wants, and the Saiyans in Universe 7 get a chance to meet others of their race. This also saves the lives of all the people in other Universes and creates a much stronger team for if Universe 7 is forced into fighting the strong Universes that didn't have to fight in the current Battle Royale.

Comment: Sounds rather interesting but I think if Goku were granted any wish after they've won the tournament I think it would be revival of the destroyed universes. This will probably result in all universes being restored, including the ones that were destroyed before the tournament took place. This will probably bring us some new refreshing villians to look forward to. That is IF Goku and his team will be granted the ability to wish. As far as I know the reward for the victor of this tournament is a "mere" survival as they were supposed to be erased.

Comment: the problem with that idea is that Zen-Oh is getting rid of these Universes for a reason - he was initially going to get rid of all of them until persuaded to have the tournament. Rather than use the dragonballs, I think Goku'd have more chance of just straight up convincing Zen-Oh to do that.